# Splitting text file without reading it

Tags: java, file

Is there any method so that I can split a text file in java without reading it?

I want to process a large text file in GB's, so I want to split file in small parts and apply thread over each file and combine result for it.

As I will be reading it for small parts then splitting a file by reading it won't make any sense as I will have to read same file for twice and it will degrade my performance.

Comment: Can we use an external tool to split the file into multiple files and use multithreading to read each one? GSplit may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your threading attempt is ill formed. If you have to do significant processing with your file data consider following threading structure:

1 Reader Thread (Reads the File and feeds the workers )

- Queue with read chunks

1..n Worker Threads (n depends on your cpu cores, processes the data chunks from the reader thread)

- Queue or dictionary with processed chunks

1 Writer Thread ( Writes results to some file)

Maybe you could combine the Reader / Writer thread into one thread because it doesn't make much sense to parallelize IO on the same physical harddisk.

It's clear that you need some synchronization stuff between the threads. Especially for queues think about semaphores

Comment: great suggestion i will surely try this one.

Answer (score 2):

Without reading the content of file you can't do that. That is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible for the following reasons:

1. How do you write a file without "reading" it?
2. You'll need to read in the text to know where a character boundary is (the encoding is not necessarily 1 byte).  This means that you cannot treat the file as binary.

Is it really not possible to read line-by line and process it like that?  That also saves additional space that the split files will take up alongside the original.  For you reference, reading a text file is simply:

```
public static void loadFileFromInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  String record = inputStream.readLine();
  while (record != null) {
    // do something with the record
    // ...
    record = inputStream.readLine();
  }
}
```

You're only reading one line at a time... so the size of the file does not impact performance at all.  You can also stop anytime you have to.  If you're adventurous you can also add the lines to separate threads to speed up processing.  That way, IO can continue churning along while you process your data.

Good luck!  If, for some reason, you do find a solution, please post it here. Thanks!

Comment: i have implemented it using line by line method in BufferedReader but i am trying for better performance better speed of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking - it cant be done without reading the file. But you also dont need to keep the entire file contents in memory to do the splitting. Just open a stream to the file and write out to other files by redirecting output to another file after certain number of bytes are written to one file. This way you are not required to keep more than one byte of file data in memory at any given time. But having a larger buffer, about 8 or 16kb will be dramatically increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Something has to read your file to split it (and you probably want to split it at line barriers, probably not at some multiple of kilobytes).

If running on Linux machine, you could delegate the splitting to an external command like [csplit](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucsplit.htm). So your Java program would simply run a `csplit yourbigfile.txt` command.

Comment: The external command will read the file and split it. Where is the benefit?

Comment: Avoiding doing it in Java. Perhaps simpler to code (since the utility already exist). Perhaps faster (but I won't bet that).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i am working on windowsXP  any other suggestion would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

In the literal sense no.  To literally split a file into smaller files, you have to read the large one and write the smaller ones.

However, I think you really want to know if you can have different threads sequentially reading different "parts" of a file at the same time.  And the answer is that you can do that.  Just have each thread create its own `RandomAccessFile` object for the file, `seek` to the relevant place, and start reading.

(A FileInputStream would probably work too, though I don't think that the Java API spec *guarantees* that `skip` is implemented using a OS level "seek" operation on the file.)

There are a couple of possible complications:

- If the file is text, you presumably want each thread to start processing at the start of some line in the file.  So each thread has to start by finding the end of a line, and make sure that it reads to the end of the last line in its "part".
- If the file uses a variable width character encoding (e.g. UTF-8), then you need to deal with the case where your partition boundaries fall in the middle of a character.

Comment: I was thinking of a RandomAccessFile, but how do you address the problem with character boundaries for non-byte encoding schemes? i.e. UTF-16, etc.

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk - by some careful encoding-aware programming.  For instance, with UTF-16 and UTF-8, the encoding scheme guarantees that you can resynchronize to a (real) character boundary in a small number of bytes.

Comment: RandomAccessFile seems to be good but i guess it works on bytes which is slower reading technique as compared to line reading. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @RamIndani - to be honest, I'm not 100% sure.  This issue won't be that it deals in bytes, because at some level so does a FileInputStream / InputStream / BufferedReader stack.  The issue would be that a RandomAccessFile doesn't do any buffering.  But you can deal with that by doing your own buffering.  But whatever way you implement it, you are going to need to think about these issues ...